# Group by and Sum in Pandas without losing columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|TradeGroup | Fund Name | Contribution | From       | To           |
|  A        | Fund_1    |   0.20       | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-02   |
|  B        | Fund_1    |   0.10       | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-02   |
|  A        | Fund_1    |   0.05       | 2013-01-03 | 2013-01-04   |
|  B        | Fund_1    |   0.45       | 2013-01-03 | 2013-01-04   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, it's contribution of a trade group to a fund on a daily basis. What I would like to do is sum up all the Contributions for a Tradegroup per day for further analysis. 
What I want to see is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|TradeGroup | Fund Name | Contribution | From       | To           |
|  A        | Fund_1    |   0.25       | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-04   |
|  B        | Fund_1    |   0.55       | 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-04   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not able to solve this using Dataframe. I've tried

```
df.groupby('TradeGroup')['Contribution'].sum()
```

However, this doesn't work. The equivalent SQL for this would be

```
Select SUM(Ctp) from Table Group By TradeGroup.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you always want the minimum `From` and the maximum `To` for the `TradeGroup` column in your output?

Comment: `df.groupby(['TradeGroup'])['Contribution'].sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the contribution column is numeric not strings to get the right matching numbers as in SQL. I think the weird nos that you are getting is due to the string nature of your 'contribution' column. Then the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a=pd.DataFrame([['A','Fund_1','0.20','2013-01-01','2013-01-02'],
['B','Fund_1','0.10','2013-01-01','2013-01-02'],['A','Fund_1','0.05','2013-
01-03','2013-01-04'],['B','Fund_1','0.45','2013-01-03','2013-01-04']],
            columns=['TraderGroup', 'Fund Name','Contribution','From', 'To'])
print a
a['Contribution'] = pd.to_numeric(a['Contribution'], errors='coerce')
b=a.groupby(['TraderGroup','Fund Name']).agg({'Contribution':np.sum,
                                         'From':'min','To':'max'}).reset_index()
print b
```

Comment: This was it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
df.groupby(['TradeGroup', 'Fund Name']).agg({'Contribution':'sum',
                                             'From':'first',
                                             'To':'last'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    TradeGroup    Fund Name  Contribution          From              To
0    A           Fund_1              0.25   2013-01-01    2013-01-04   
1    B           Fund_1              0.55   2013-01-01    2013-01-04
```

Or you can use `min` and `max` instead of `first` and `last` if your dataframe isn't ordered.

Comment: Thanks for you help. However, I'm getting really weird nos for Contribution sum.
For eg: -0.0135596483407320.01442512535932610.00866804...
which is incorrect when compared with SQL output

Comment: Can you provide data showing really weird numbers?  This works with the given example.

Comment: Missing data, ie NaN maybe handled differently between sql and pandas.

Comment: There is no missing data. The database is huge. About 3GB. Here is a sample of Contribution
0.0003936101689380279,

Comment: This is a straight forward calculation, you're going to have to do some trouble shooting.  Sorry, syntax is pretty easy find your problem is going to take some time.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'd have to dig in more!. Appreciate your help though. Thanks